# How to protect registries from using deleteservice?

Tags: c, windows, driver, wdk

I implemented the following code to protect registries for using `cmregistercallback`.

When 'Windows Registry Edit' access a registry, my code works very well.

But when I used `cmd - sc delete 'service'` for administrator authority, The registry was deleted.

```
NTSTATUS RegistryFilterCallback(IN PVOID _CallbackContext, IN PVOID _FuncClass, IN PVOID _RegKeyInfo)
{
    UNREFERENCED_PARAMETER(_CallbackContext);
    NTSTATUS Status = STATUS_SUCCESS;
    REG_NOTIFY_CLASS NotifyClass = (REG_NOTIFY_CLASS)(ULONG_PTR)_FuncClass;

    if (IsAllowProcess()== TRUE)
    {
        return Status;
    }

    switch (NotifyClass)
    {
        case RegNtPreOpenKeyEx:
        {
            PREG_CREATE_KEY_INFORMATION RegInfo = (PREG_CREATE_KEY_INFORMATION)_RegKeyInfo;

            if (RegPreOpenKey(RegInfo->RootObject, RegInfo->CompleteName))
            {
                DbgPrint("RegNtPreOpenKeyEx : Prevent Opening Handle\n");
                Status = STATUS_ACCESS_DENIED;
            }

            break;
        }

        case RegNtPreDeleteKey:
        {
                DbgPrint("RegNtDeleteKey : Prevent delete Handle\n");

                Status = MyDeleteKey((PUNICODE_STRING)_RegKeyInfo);

                break;
        }
        case RegNtPreDeleteValueKey:

            DbgPrint("RegNtPreDeleteValueKey : Prevent delete Handle\n");

            break;

        case RegNtPreUnLoadKey:

            DbgPrint("RegNtPreUnLoadKey : Prevent delete Handle\n");

            break;
    }

    return Status;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I don't know what `IsAllowProcess` does but it probably only blocks "user processes"?

The SCM is running as System and it probably deletes the registry key, not sc.exe.

Administrators can start a cmd.exe instance as System with various tricks. The real solution is to not give untrusted users administrator accounts.